# Multiple Store URL

Tags: magento2, url, stores, multiple

I've spent more than a week to solve the problem with URL's in my Multiple Stores in Magento Community 2.3.2, but I got nothing.

What I need:

URL structure: example.com/store_name/store_viewname 
instead of typical example.com/store_viewname offered by Magento 2 with "Add Store Code to Urls" activated.

What I've done:

1) Created Website - Store - Store View.

2) Added individual Secured and Non-secured Base URL and Base Link URL for each store like: http://example.com/store_name/ and https://example.com/store_name/

3) Pointed proper CMS Home page in Default pages

4) Created subfolder with index.php and .htaccess with modifications:

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; #tried /../app/ also
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'store_viewname'; 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

and .htaccess below RewriteEngine = On:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.example\.com/store_name MAGE_RUN_CODE=store_viewname
SetEnvIf Host www\.example\.com/store_name MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^example\.com/store_name MAGE_RUN_CODE=store_viewname
SetEnvIf Host ^megamolis\.ru/store_name MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store_name/.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store_name$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:store_viewname]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1,E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:store]`
```

Of course, Cache Flashed and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f after changes. And symlinks of app, pub, lib, var added to the subfolder.
Moreover, I tried to create subfolders both in example.com and example.com/pub for checking.

What I've got:

example.com/store_name

```
Whoops, our bad...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

It seems 404.

This error designed in the style of Magento. example.com/static and example.com/media work in design of DEFAULT store. Because I added the path (Base URLs) to example.com/static/ and example.com/media/ in Store Config.

example.com/store_name/store_viewname has the same result

And if I try to change the store to default it redirects to https://example.com/store_name/store_viewname/stores/store/redirect/ instead of example.com

example.com works perfectly.
I need your help. Thank you.

Now, I want to add some information: I use Apache + NGINX

Store config in Magento Admin Panel:

Url Options

Auto-redirect to Base URL - Yes (302 Found)

Search Engine Optimization

Use Web Server Rewrites - Yes

Base URLs

Base URL - http://example.com/store_name/
Base Link URL - http://example.com/store_name/
Base URL for Static View Files - http://example.com/static/
Base URL for User Media Files - http://example.com/media/

Base URLs (Secure)

Secure Base URL - https:... the same above
Secure Base Link URL - https:... the same above
Secure Base URL for Static View Files - https:... the same above
Secure Base URL for User Media Files - https:... the same above
Use Secure URLs on Storefront - Yes
Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) - No
Upgrade Insecure Requests - Yes

Default Pages

Default Web URL - cms
CMS Home Page - Store_name_page
Default No-route URL - cms/noroute/index
CMS No Route Page - 404 Not Found 1
CMS No Cookies Page - Enable Cookies
Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages - Yes

Default Cookie Settings

Cookie Lifetime - 3600
Cookie Path -
Cookie Domain -
Use HTTP Only - Yes

Browser Capabilities Detection

Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled - Yes
Show Notice if JavaScript is Disabled - Yes
Show Notice if Local Storage is Disabled - No

Answer (score 0):

You must accord your code based on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

```
MAGE_RUN_TYPE can be either store or website
Use website to load a website in your storefront.
Use store to load any store view in your storefront.
MAGE_RUN_CODE is the unique website or store view code that corresponds to MAGE_RUN_TYPE
```

Can you post a screenshot of your stores configuration?

You can also read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

Comment: As you see in my question, the "store" is applied everywhere in the code.